# SBT - conditionally set exportJars setting based on task

Tags: sbt, scala.js

I have a mixed server side Scala / Scala.js project, built to a runnable jar. I'm using the sbt-revolver plugin to restart the main class on change of any files, and ~ fastOptJS to recompile the JS on change to the client side files.

I'd like not to restart the main class if only client side files have changed, as it's making the feedback cycle slow. I use a task I've defined called "build" to copy the jars around to where I want them (for Docker) as so:

```
exportJars := true
mainClass in appJVM := Some("myproject.Server")

packageOptions in (appJVM, Compile, packageBin) += ManifestAttributes( "Class-Path" -> externalDependencyClasspath.in(appJVM, Runtime).value.files.map { file => s"dependencies/${file.name}" }.mkString(" ") )

lazy val build = taskKey[Unit]("Ensures jars are in the right places for Docker")
build := {

  val packagedDir = new File(target.value, "packaged")
  IO.delete(packagedDir)
  val dependenciesDir = new File(target.value, "packaged/dependencies")
  dependenciesDir.mkdirs()

  val (_, artifactFile) = packagedArtifact.in(appJVM, Compile, packageBin).value
  Files.copy(artifactFile.toPath, new File(packagedDir, artifactFile.getName).toPath, COPY_ATTRIBUTES)

  externalDependencyClasspath.in(appJVM, Runtime, build).value.files.foreach { file =>
    Files.copy(file.toPath, new File(dependenciesDir, file.name).toPath, COPY_ATTRIBUTES)
  }
}
```

However, this means that when I use `appJVM/reStart` it actually runs the jar file, which in turn means that in order to change the client side JS the jar file has to be rebuilt and the server has to be restarted.

If I set `exportJars := false` then `appJVM/reStart` runs my project from the classes directory, so only running fastOptJS will let me see my changes without needing to restart the server.

Is there a way to conditionally set `exportJars` depending on whether I'm running the build task or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My final conclusion was that if I entirely removed the `exportJars` setting, but made build depend on `packagedArtifact.in(appJVM, Compile, packageBin)` then I got the best of both worlds. `reStart` ran from the classes directory, so resources could be changed on the fly, but I still got a jar build that I could copy into the right place.

(This still leaves `internalDependencyClasspath` returning the classes dir rather than a jar - I have no solution to that other than to work around it by not using `internalDependencyClasspath`.)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's as simple as moving setting `exportJars` it into my `build` task as so:

```
build := {
  exportJars := true
  ...
}
```

Comment: No that's a no-op. Settings are immutable. You're just creating an immutable value of type `Setting[_]` that represents the association `exportJars := true`, and then you throw away that value.
I don't think what you're trying to do is possible. What you *could* do is define a *command* that first `set exportJars := true` then calls `build`. Search for `addCommandAlias`.

Comment: Thanks @sjrd - looks like I was misdiagnosing. What I was trying to achieve was actually achieved just by removing the ```exportJars``` setting altogether. Then ```reStart``` runs from the ```classes``` directory, but the reference to ```packagedArtifact.in(appJVM, Compile, packageBin)``` in the ```build``` task seems to be enough to force it to create a jar file anyway.